# Module has no Attribute "Arrange"

Tags: python, numpy

Very simple lines of code

```
import numpy as np 

arrange_values = np.arrange(0,30,2)

print arrange_values
```

I already did some research into this topic and I know that the numpy version is the 1.11.2 installed, which should contain the "`arrange`" attribute. I've also added C:\Python27 to the system's path and it still doesn't function.

Also, numpy works with other attributes when I use them. The "`array`" attribute functions properly. So `numpy` is functional in my text editor, just not when I want to use the "`arrange`" function.

Does someone know how I can change this?

Comment: you need one `r` in word `arange`

Comment: When in doubt, refer to the API. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: Also, the method is read as "a range" as in "a range of values", not "arrange these values"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`arange`** instead of *`arrange`*. This fixes your problem.

```
import numpy as np

arange_values = np.arange(0, 30, 2)

print arange_values
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow....I had no idea about that...thanks a lot guys...I really didn't see it...